# Why am I missing Android UI elements in Xamarin Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

I'm developing a simple Android app in Visual Studio using .NET and Xamarin. Everything is going well except that I seem to missing certain UI elements. Specifically, I'm missing the Spinner class. Is there something simple I should have done when setting up Visual Studio 2019 for Android Xamarin development that would have made these available?

Here is the error when I try to include a Spinner in the XAML file:

```
The type 'Spinner' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
```

Now it may be that Android widgets are not available in Xamarin-- if that's the case, someone please set me straight. I can't confirm with my research, though, whether that's the case.

Here is all the version info for my Visual Studio build, Xamarin, etc. I'm building for Android 9.0.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.4.1
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.4.1+29609.76
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.03056

Installed Version: Community

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   16.4.457.38025
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

C# Tools   3.4.1-beta4-19607-02+52d275c4f82f329a9732b078c7f7fa0e45cd3e84
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Extensibility Message Bus   1.2.0 (d16-2@8b56e20)
Provides common messaging-based MEF services for loosely coupled Visual Studio extension components communication and integration.

IntelliCode Extension   1.0
IntelliCode Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers

Mono Debugging for Visual Studio   16.5.23 (1b51e8c)
Support for debugging Mono processes with Visual Studio.

NuGet Package Manager   5.4.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

ProjectServicesPackage Extension   1.0
ProjectServicesPackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Visual Basic Tools   3.4.1-beta4-19607-02+52d275c4f82f329a9732b078c7f7fa0e45cd3e84
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual F# Tools 10.4 for F# 4.6   16.4.0-beta.19556.5+e7597deb7042710a7142bdccabd6f92b0840d354
Microsoft Visual F# Tools 10.4 for F# 4.6

Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0
Interop layer for hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio

VisualStudio.DeviceLog   1.0
Information about my package

VisualStudio.Foo   1.0
Information about my package

VisualStudio.Mac   1.0
Mac Extension for Visual Studio

Xamarin   16.4.000.306 (d16-4@564b8d0)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin Designer   16.4.0.464 (remotes/origin/d16-4@4abf337c3)
Visual Studio extension to enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.

Xamarin Templates   16.4.25 (579ee62)
Templates for building iOS, Android, and Windows apps with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms.

Xamarin.Android SDK   10.1.1.0 (d16-4/f2c9364)
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
    Mono: bef1e63
    Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d16-4@c4e569f
    ProGuard: xamarin/proguard/master@905836d
    SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.28.0@46204c4
    Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/master@9f4ed4b


Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   13.8.3.0 (0d8fe21)
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
```

Comment: Which version of Xamarin Forms do you use? What Android OS level target? Please specify in detail.

Comment: Copy / pasted the Visual Studio version info, in case that would help.

Comment: @Trekkie, Do you want to use Spinner in Xamarin.forms? I think it is the control in Xamarin.Forms, I think you can use this to replace spinner:https://github.com/amccorma/xamarin-amccorma/tree/master/Forms.DropDown

Comment: That seems viable, but my question is why am I missing Spinner in the first place

Comment: @Trekkie,Sorry for my firstly comment, I think the spinner is not the control in Xamarin.forms, You want to use it in PCL? It can use in Android.

Comment: I’m guessing that you have already tried quitting visual studio and deleting all the temporary files in the bin, obj, vs and NuGet folders, and then trying rebuild? If that doesn’t work then make sure that you have the right Xamarin Forms NuGet package version, try to tweak and see if the error goes away? If that doesn’t work, make sure that when you’re building android, you “Unload” all the other projects that are not needed. If that doesn’t work, do you want to share your solution of Github so we can check it out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to **Xamarin**!

If you want to create a pure **Xamarin.Android** application (and use widgets like Spinner, etc) you have to create an **Android App** by choosing the option in red in the image below in **Visual Studio 2019**:

[image]

There you will have access to most, if not all the **widgets** that **Android** has to offer. Refer to [**Xamarin** docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/) for more details.

To create a **Spinner** with **Xamarin.Android**, you can also find a [tutorial in the **Xamarin** docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/spinner).

Now, back to your question and the error you get:

To me it looks like you created a **Xamarin.Forms** solution and there you are trying to implement a **Spinner** (i see this from the error you got, and since you are speaking of **XAML** which is only available for **Xamarin.Forms** applications!). If this is your case, you should know that **Spinner** is not defined in **Xamarin.Forms**!

If you really want to create a **Xamarin.Forms** **Application** (in case you really want to go Cross Platform!) you can still use the **Spinner**: again, **Xamarin** docu has some information on how to use **Native** views in **Xamarin.Forms**.

On the other hand, if you really want to use **Xamarin.Forms**, and want to share as much code as possible, you should take a look at [**Picker**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/).

Comment: The other answer was useful information, but this is definitely the root of my issue; thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have to re/install the NuGet packages for the used support libraries.

Here is a list of all available libraries:
https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Xamarin+support

You can also find them in the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio